# How to get platform dependent output filename with QMake?

Tags: qt, qmake

Assume I have a qmake project file `*.pro`:

```
# some stuff ...

TARGET = my_binary

# other stuff...

include( $$PWD/post.pri )
```

And inside the `post.pri` file (because I would like to reuse whatever this `*.pri` file does), I would like to get the **complete** name of the output file.

For example if is an `app`, then on windows I would like to get `my_binary.exe` and on linux `my_binary`. Or if the project is a shared lib, I would like to get `my_binary.dll` or `libmy_binary.so` respectively. Same if is a static lib, I would expect `my_binary.lib` and `libmy_binary.a`.

I have already tried the *undocumented* qmake variable `QMAKE_FILE_OUT` but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your .pro script:

```
load(resolve_target)
message($$QMAKE_RESOLVED_TARGET)
```

It will output the build path and target name, according to your platform and project TEMPLATE.

Comment: Noice! It works. Care to explain why, how this works? Is this docuemented somewhere or some undocumented functionality? The `load()` part puzzles me the most.

Comment: to discard the output path: `$$basename(QMAKE_RESOLVED_TARGET)`

Comment: `resolve_target.prf` is a feature, that you can find at your QTDIR/mkspecs directory, along with many other very useful scripts, used internally by qmake. Beware that this is internal matter, and they put a prominent WARNING at the top of the file saying they may change or even remove this file as they see fit. You can read it, it is a text file.

Comment: [load(feature_file)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-test-function-reference.html#load-feature) is well documented, but resolve_target.prf is not.